# Button & EditText setOnLongClickListener bugs

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, android-button, onlongclicklistener

I have some views in my program which I would want the user to drag. One of them is a `Button` and another is an `EditText`. I would like the Button to be unclickable and the EditText to be unenabled, **but**, still be draggable (activate the onLongClick method).
How can I do this?

Implementation code below:

```
//The button
views.add(new Button(this));
...
views.get(views.size() - 1).setOnLongClickListener(this);
views.get(views.size() - 1).setClickable(false);

//The EditText
views.add(new EditText(this));
...
views.get(views.size() - 1).setEnabled(false);
views.get(views.size() - 1).setLongClickable(true);
views.get(views.size() - 1).setOnLongClickListener(this);
```

P.S - added to the EditText `setLongClickable(true)` but it still didn't work...

[App work example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtJQ2.gif)
(as you can see, other views drag regularly, the buttons drags too but is still clickable and the EditText is unenabled but also undruggable)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked this problem!
Instead of `setOnLongClickListener` I'm using `setOnTouchListener` in wich I make `startDragAndDrop`, and for unenabling the EditText and still dragging it I used `setFocusable(false)`. Now it's working even better.
[New implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efNBk.gif)